# Can't access field of document that is visible by printjson

Tags: mongodb

this is my first time posting a question here, but I'm out of ideas.

I inherited a very big dataset, that I want to transfer to MongoDB.
In its simplest collection, it looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57fe2d5d666d9be427d89017"),
    "A_ID" : 1234234,
    "Other_ID" : 1234
}
```

I did a csv-mongoimport after converting the csv from UCS-2 to UTF-8 with Notepad++ (mongoimport didnt accept UCS-2).

If I query by "Other_ID", I get what I want:

```
db.getCollection('...').count({Other_ID: 1234})
-> 26611
```

If I query by B_ID, I dont get what I expect:

```
db.getCollection('...').count({A_ID: 1234})
-> 0
```

But if I do:

```
db.getCollection('...').count({A_ID: null})
-> 450124
```

We got as far as noticing that the charset is different - loading in Webstorm showed the difference, Notepad++ just started to exhibit strange behaviour (changing fonts in-file, changing font while moving over the text with the cursor,..).

So if I copy and paste the A_ID and do the same query again, it works:

```
db.getCollection('...').count({A_ID: 1234})
-> 4
```

I wanted to tell this to the world, I couldn't find anything related to that - and there is a remaining question - how can I normalize my field entries to be in ASCII? 
Do I have to find those fields and replace them manually with a script? What would be a reliable way to find those fields?

Comment: Post few documents which are available in your collection and satisfying db.getCollection('...').count({A_ID: 1234})

Comment: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("57fe2d5d666d9be427d89026"),
    "A_ID" : 1234,
    "Umstand_ID" : 123
}

Would satisfy 
db.getCollection('...').count({A_ID: 1234})
but not
db.getCollection('...').count({A_ID: 1234})

I cannot post this using the original Charset. And yes, there is a difference.